# Remotely Connecting to SQL Server Express Instance

Tags: sql-server

I receive the following error when trying to connect to a remote SQL Express instance:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476
```

I initially tried accessing the server with SQL Server credentials. No success.

I have:

1. Ensured remote connections are enabled
2. Ensured TCP Protocol is enabled
3. Ensured SQL Server Browser is started

Then I tried the "Run As" command to run ssms.exe as another user with appropriate credentials. I still receive the same error. What might the issue be?

A couple of specific questions:

- What is the "right" server name - I have been putting in the instance
  name "NAME\NAME"?
- When I am running as a different user, what is the appropriate
  authentication mode: Windows, SQL Server, Active Directory Password,
  or Active Directory Integrated?

Thanks for any help. The remote instance is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic port entry has to be given along with the SQLExpress login

SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS,45490

```
`Data Source=127.2.3.4\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=dbase;User ID=sa;Password=password`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried, and am now getting the following error: TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------



A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 11001)

Comment: Please post your connection string.  Have your tried by IP versus server name?

Comment: I updated my answer to have a complete sample.  Does yours match this ( updating IP and Init Catalog, and user info of  course )?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I am sorry if I did not clarify this earlier, but I am attempting to connect through SQL Server Management studio. So I do not have a connection string exactly but am using the following: MIDAM\MIDAM,5046. Also, please excuse my ignorance, but what where could I find the IP address. When I navigate to properties in the remote SQL Server Management Studio it just shows the named server instance (MIDAM\MIDAM) for the server name. Thanks.

Comment: MIDAM is the server name and the database name is also MIDAM?

Comment: The database name is not, but the server and instance name are both MIDAM. When I try PING, it says "could not find host MIDAM". Thanks.

Comment: ok, so your issue is specifically exactly what the error says.  you need to resolve the name to ip issue.  Maybe ask the server admin what the IP is?