# Issue connecting Windows app to SQL Server that is in another computer in a virtual machine

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms, sqlconnection

My PC is running Windows 10 x64 which has a virtual machine that is a Windows 7 x86. This virtual machine has a SQL Server instance `SQLEXPRESS`. This server is provisional, in the future we are going to use another computer, this is for testing purposes.

I have developed a Windows desktop app which connects to this server to read and write.

Here is the connection string:

```
<add name="Importacion" 
     connectionString="Data Source=WIN-EIUKNBIVIED\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Importacion;User Id=administrador;Password=contraseña" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This has been developed in C# in Visual Studio. I have created an installer with all the dependencies. It works in the virtual machine.

**Problem**

When I install it on another computer, I get a SQL Server error #28.

**Hints**

- Ping in virtual machine works to `SQLEXPRESS`
- Ping from native PC to virtual machine works
- Ping from native PC to `SQLEXPRESS` doesn't work

**Things that I already tried**

- Enabling TCP/IP ports
- Setting to connection to the server as mixed (Windows and SQL Server)
- Disabling firewall on both computers
- The new user that use the connection string have permission to do everything
- The remote connection is enabled

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server Express cannot connect error: 28 - Server doesn't support requested protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238219/sql-server-express-cannot-connect-error-28-server-doesnt-support-requested-p)

Comment: which TCP/IP port did you enable?

Comment: Thanks Gareth, but no. I have already check that.  
VietDD, I don't remember but I can take a look, how relevant is the number?

Comment: I think you need to open port 1433 for inbound setting.

Comment: That's the port that I opened.

Comment: may be you should try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40158156/2133965

Comment: I have already check that post too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223445/discussion-between-vietdd-and-raulmd13).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out.

When you create a DataConnection in Visual Studio 2019, the connection string is setup as Windows login. Even if you change it manually to add a SQL autentication, it doesn't use it as SQL login.
If you want to use SQL login, you will have to make a new DataConnection.

I hope it helps someone in the future.